# Add value from row to date in SELECT query

Tags: sqlite

Assume I have the following SQLite table "foobar":

```
id | start      | duration
---+------------+---------
1  | 2016-05-12 | 2
2  | 2016-01-01 | 5
```

My goal is to get the sum of the start-date and the duration (durations are in years).
So my desired result is the following:

```
id | end
---+-----------
1  | 2018-05-12
2  | 2021-01-01
```

Is this possible with a single query?

I know it is possible to add static values as follows

```
SELECT date(start, "+2 years") FROM foobar;
```

but I could not find a way to replace the static `2` with the dynamic value of `duration`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT date(start, "+" || duration || " years") 
FROM foobar;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8bb66/2)

Comment: This was probably to simple to come to my mind... Thanks!